# Automatically convert percentage input values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, cakephp

Several of the form fields in an application I am building using CakePHP collect percentages for their values.  I would like the users to be to see and edit percentages in the familiar percentage (24.5%) format, but I want to store it in decimal (.245) format in order to ease calculation logic.  Since there's several of these fields, I'd rather not have to write the conversion logic into the controllers for every single percentage field.

Is anyone aware of a simple solution to automatically performing this conversion, or am I stuck writing a custom helper/behavior to solve this problem?

**Solution**

I ended up writing a jQuery plugin that handles this.  Here it is, for anyone who might need it in the future:

```
/**
 * Input Percent
 * 
 * Percentages are tricky to input because users like seeing them as 24.5%, but
 * when using them in calculation their value is actually .245.  This plugin
 * takes a supplied field and automatically creates a percentage input.
 * 
 * It works by taking an input element and creating a hidden input with the same
 * name immediately following it in the DOM.  This has the effect of submitting
 * the proper value instead of the human only one.  An onchange method is then
 * bound to the original input in order to keep the two synced.
 * 
 * Potential Caveats:
 *   * There will be two inputs with the same name.  Make sure anything you
 *     script against this field is prepared to handle that.
 *     
 * @author Brad Koch <kochb@aedisit.com>
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.inputPercent = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var display_field = this;
            var value_field = $('<input type="hidden" />').get(0);

            // Initialize and attach the hidden input.
            $(value_field).attr('name', $(this).attr('name'));
            $(value_field).val($(display_field).val());
            $(display_field).after(value_field);
            $(display_field).after('%');

            // Convert the display field's proper percent value into the display format.
            if (isFinite($(display_field).val())) {
                $(display_field).val($(display_field).val() * 100);
            }

            // Enable synchronization between the two.
            $(this).bind('change', function () {
                var value = $(display_field).val();

                // Handle non-numeric values.
                if (isFinite(value)) {
                    $(value_field).val(value / 100);
                } else {
                    $(value_field).val(value);
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('input.percent').inputPercent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write some simple javascript (use whatever your favourite framework is, or plain js) to convert fields with a class of #percentage just before submit.

Alternatively, and also dealing with users without javascript; in the model, add the beforeSave() method, check if the number is < 1 or not and if not, divide by 100.

You could also add a simple component or helper to convert the internal number back to a percentage for display, if NumberHelper can't help.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  My implementation of this is posted on the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a helper for this - the NumberHelper

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1455/toPercentage

The only drawback that I have found is that if you store your data as a decimal representation of a percentage (ie .045 = 4.5%) instead of as the actual percentage (ie .045 = .045%) then you will have to multiply by 100 before converting.

ie:

```
<?php echo $this->Number->toPercentage( 51.5 ); // 51.5% ?>
<?php echo $this->Number->toPercentage( .245 * 100 ); // 24.5% ?>
```

Comment: Another option (if the data is coming from the primary table in your query ie. not a related table) is to use a virtualField. So you can simply add a virtualField entry that takes the raw field and calculates a percentage field on the fly.

Comment: i would always use a helper in the view - on demand. why using virtual fields if the percentage might not be used anywhere in the view?

Comment: This solution has the formatting part down, except that only handles the display logic.. I still would have to do the converting on my own.  Virtual fields don't solve the problem unfortunately, as there's a reporting application reading from this DB as well.  Mark is right; some kind of helper/JS input widget is what I'll need.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a plugin to convert from and to json to store in the DB.
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/models/behaviors/jsonable.php

you could easily modify it to convert from and to percentage.
you need some custom

afterFind

and

beforeSave

to do so.

then attach it to your model like so:

$actsAs = array('Percentage');